# How to get correct information using php-graph-sdk

Tags: php, facebook

I'm using the php-graph-sdk v. 5.5 to get information of a user facebook that signs up in a web. The problem is that there's no way to know if a token is valid or not, using the methods like

> FacebookAuthenticationAccessToken->getExpiresAt()

and so on. Those methods always return null values even if the token is valid. I'd like to check the token validity before call the ->get() method of the main FacebookFacebook class. Is there any way to do ti?

Comment: Debug the token here, and see what that says: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/ And you don’t really need to check token validity before making requests ... the API will tell you in the response if your request failed because of an invalid token.

Comment: The problem is that I need to check programmatically, not using online tools, due this is done by a webserive. I'd like to get token validation before perform the ->get() method call to improve webservice performance

Comment: I asked you to check manually, so that we can see whether this is a problem with your code or not. // So instead of making one request to the API and seeing what the result is, you want to rather make one request to check the token validity first, and then do the actual request that fetches data afterwards ... and you really think making two requests instead of one is going to _improve_ performance …?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! This is not the getExpiresAt() method that must be call. This is only a getter that gets the same information you posted in the constructor of

```
$accessToken = new \Facebook\Authentication\AccessToken($this->accessToken, $expirationDate);
```

You must set the var $expirationDate to a valid timestamp, and this is directly the value that getExpiresAt() returns, so doesn't has sense to use to check the Access Token validation.
To get the correct expiration date of an access token, you must perform a remote call using a Request as follows:

```
try {
    $response = $this->fb->get('/debug_token?input_token=' . $this->accessToken);
}
catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    $this->lastError = 'FaReEx: ' . $e->getMessage();
    return false;
} 
catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    $this->lastError = 'FaSDKEx: ' . $e->getMessage();
    return false;
}

$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
return $graphObject->getProperty('expires_at'); // This is a DateTime php object
```